# Map firestore data to React-big-Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-calendar

**EDITED:**

I am now using [react-big-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package//react-big-calendar) which is nearly achieving my goal.

I have been able to map the data from my Firestore collection onto this calendar and show on the calendar as an event.

However, currently it is mapping each document from the firstore collection with its own calendar, with just one event on each calendar, so there is a row of lots of individual calendars - one for each firestore document.

I can't work out how to get all of the documents to show as events on one single calendar.

Here is the code that is currently doing this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, date, getDate, getMonth, getFullYear } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer, dateFnsLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import { Firestoredb } from '../../../../../firebase';
import { onSnapshot, collection, getDocs, getDoc, doc, query, orderBy, where, setDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import format from "date-fns/format";
import getDay from "date-fns/getDay";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
import startOfWeek from "date-fns/startOfWeek";

export default function Calendar2() {


    const locales = {
      "en-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US"),
    };
    const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
      format,
      parse,
      startOfWeek,
      getDay,
      locales,
    });



    const [collectionId2, setCollectionId2] = useState('Primary School Bookings')
    const [Courses2, setCourses2] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      getCourses2()
    }, [])
  
    useEffect(() =>{
      console.log(Courses2)
    }, [Courses2]) 
  
    function getCourses2() {

      const courseCollectionRef = collection(Firestoredb, collectionId2)
      const q = query(courseCollectionRef, where('facilitator', '==', ''))
      getDocs(q)
      .then(response => {
        const content = response.docs.map(doc => ({
          data: doc.data(), 
          id: doc.id,
        }))
        setCourses2(content)
  
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.messaage))
    }





  return (
    <div>calendar2
        <br/>

  
  <ul className='SchoolInfoContainer2'>
              
              {Courses2.map(course => <li className='OneSchool2' 
              key={course.id}
              id = {course.id}>

<Calendar
      localizer={localizer}
      events={[
        {
        title: course.data.schoolName,
        allDay: false,
        start: new Date(course.data.visitDate),
        end: new Date(course.data.visitDate),
        }]}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                style={{ height: 500 }}
              />
                </li>)}
                
            </ul>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you are already mapping the response with content variable. Why can't you use data from content?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by mapping the data first:

```
const data = Courses2.map((course => {
             
  return {
      title: course.data.schoolName,
      allDay: false,
      start: new Date(course.data.visitDate),
      end: new Date(course.data.visitDate),
  };
  
}));
```

And then putting that const into the Calendar:

```
<Calendar
    
      localizer={localizer}
      events={data}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      style={{ height: 500 }
      
    />
```